# How to randomly rename all files in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I just recently extracted source code of an apk from playstore. When I opened the source code all the function names, variable names were renamed with some random numbers and letters.

So does playstore does that automatically when we upload our apk?
If not then how can I do that in android studio?

Comment: I can only think of two reasons you'd want to do this. 1: You think it will make your app more secure somehow, or 2: You're writing malware. My responses are 1: No it won't, and 2: Don't do that.

Comment: ad. 2: malware have nothing to do with this, ad. 1: yep, thats for safety

Answer (score 0):

thats Proguard feature, check this doc: [Shrink, obfuscate, and optimize your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code)

when you use it then your code will be obfuscated for harder reverse engineering (besides some optimisation). you have to enable this feature in your gradle file (`minifyEnabled`), some same how to declare under link above

Answer (score 0):

> So does playstore does that automatically when we upload our apk?
> -no it was done by some other application

the application you unpacked was previously obfuscated. 
you can read more about this here:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)

Java obfuscator

> https://www.preemptive.com/products/jsdefender?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI4bXBqZn48AIVbxitBh1OyQnqEAAYASAAEgJ_XPD_BwE